# Цикл обработки полей формы и добавления записи в БД

Tags: php

Привет! Помогите решить задачу. Как я понимаю, она достаточно простая, но я только пытаюсь разобраться с PHP.

Суть вопроса/задачи: у меня есть поля ввода в форме, которых, в зависимости от условий, может быть до 30. И они могут быть не все заполнены (т.е. 1-12, 14,15 с записями 13, 16 без, потом опять с записями и т.д.).

Каждое поле я обрабатываю следующим образом:

```
// если заполнена первая кнопка
if ($_POST['BT1_pair']) {       
    if ( $_POST['distribution_board'] == 'ШР') $_POST['BT1_distribution'] = 'Р'.$_POST['BT1_distribution'];
    else if ( $_POST['distribution_board'] == 'MJ21V00' || $_POST['distribution_board'] == 'MJ22V00' || $_POST['distribution_board'] = 'MJ23V00' ) {
         $_POST['BT1_distribution'] = 'ПК'.$_POST['BT1_distribution'];  } 
    // добавляем к индексу №
    $_POST['distribution_board'] = $_POST['block'].''.$_POST['distribution_board'];
    //$_POST['code_connections'] = $_POST['btn_two_index'].'.'.$_POST['btn_two'].':'.$_POST['btn_one_index'].'.'.$_POST['btn_one'];
    // формируем шифр       
    $_POST['code_btn'] = $_POST['distribution_board'].'.'.$_POST['BT1_distribution'].'.'.$_POST['BT1_pair'];
    //делаем запись в базу
    mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `GGS_btn` 
        VALUES ('', '$_POST[index]', '1', '$_POST[distribution_board]', '$_POST[BT1_distribution]', '$_POST[BT1_pair]', '$_POST[code_btn]' )"); 
}
```

Пока написал только для одной кнопки, но понимаю, что можно сделать цикл и к BT (BT1) увеличивать число до 30 и таким образом обработать все поля. Но пока не смог это реализовать, не хватает знаний...

Буду крайне признателен за помощь в реализации задачи!

Comment: Для каждого поля будет одинаковая проверка?

Comment: Ну так `for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++) { if ($_POST['BT'.$i.'_pair']) ... }` А вообще поля в форме называли бы `BT_pair[0], BT_pair[1]` и т.п. И был бы у вас на входе готовый массив

Comment: @KernelPanic да, одинаковая.

Comment: @Mike вынеси в ответ. Меня твой вариант более чем устраивает! Так и предполагал, что всё должно быть предельно просто.
Единственное, чёт не получается склеить вот эту строку `VALUES ('', '$_POST[index]', '$i', '$_POST[distribution_board]', '$_POST[BT1_distribution]', '$_POST[BT1_pair]', '$_POST[code_btn]' )");`

Comment: Василий, про SQL инъекции слышал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса. Надо использовать привязку переменных. Кроме того более эффективно подготовить запрос один раз и потом его вызывать несколько раз внутри цикла. Таким образом мы избегаем стадии компиляции каждого запроса в БД.

С учетом сказанного может выглядеть как то так:

```
// Подготавливаем запрос. Вместо переменных ставим знаки "?"
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `GGS_btn` VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
if(! $stmt) { обработка ошибки создания запроса }

// Привязываем переменные (в порядке следования "?" в запросе)
// Буквы в первой строке - типы параметров 's'-строка, 'i' - integer
$stmt->bind_param("sissss",$_POST['index'], $i, $dboard, $dist, $pair, $cbtn);

// Заполняем фиксированные параметры
$dboard = $_POST['block'].''.$_POST['distribution_board'];

for($i=1; $i<=30; $i++) {
  if ($_POST['BT'.$i.'_pair']) {       
    if ( $_POST['distribution_board'] == 'ШР') $dist = 'Р'.$_POST['BT'.$i.'_distribution'];
    else if ( $_POST['distribution_board'] == 'MJ21V00' || $_POST['distribution_board'] == 'MJ22V00' || $_POST['distribution_board'] = 'MJ23V00' ) {
         $dist = 'ПК'.$_POST['BT'.$i.'_distribution'];  } 
    else { $dist=$_POST['BT'.$i.'_distribution']; }
    // формируем шифр       
    $cbtn = $_POST['distribution_board'].'.'.$_POST['BT'.$i.'_distribution'].'.'.$_POST['BT'.$i.'_pair'];

    $pair = $_POST['BT'.$i.'_pair'];
    // Выполняем запрос.
    // Будут использованы текущие значения из переменных, привязанных перед циклом.
    if( ! $stmt->execute() ) { обработка ошибки вставки }
  }
}
$stmt->close();
```

Так же очень рекомендую всегда перечислять имена столбцов в предложениях `INSERT INTO GGS_btn(col1, col2, ...) VALUES(..)`. Во первых вы сразу в коде видите какую переменную в какую колонку вы реально вставляете. Не надо сверятся с структурой таблицы каждый раз читая код. Во вторых, при изменениях структуры таблицы, у вас не будут появляться сложно вылавливаемые ошибки по всему приложению.

А что касается полей формы, лучше называйте их вроде `<input ... name='BT_pair[1]'>`, тогда в коде можно будет использовать гораздо легче читаемое `$_POST['BT_pair'][1]`.

Comment: Спасибо!! Но у меня такой вариант не пишет в базу, хотя ошибок нет.

Comment: Сделал так:
`for( $i=1; $i<=30; $i++ ) { 
  if ($_POST['BT'.$i.'_pair']) {  
   if ( $_POST['distribution_board'] == 'ШР') $_POST['BT'.$i.'_distribution'] = 'Р'.$_POST['BT'.$i.'_distribution'];
   
   // присваиваем значения переменным
   $pair = $_POST['BT'.$i.'_pair'];
   $distribution = $_POST['BT'.$i.'_distribution'];
   // делаем запись в базу
   mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `GGS_btn` 
    VALUES ('', '$_POST[index]', '$i', '$_POST[distribution_board]', '$distribution', '$pair', '$_POST[code_btn]' )"); 
  }
 }`
Код сократил, чтобы влез в комментарий.

Comment: @VasilyUK Проверьте еще ошибки при bind_param, может у вас там типы колонок не совпадают (число-строка) (буквы 's' - это строки, их так же должно быть столько же сколько "?"). Вижу у вас там еще переменная $i в запрос передается. Вы соответствующую ей букву 'i' в bind поставили ? Я перед публикацией проверял что то похожее, вставило нормально. Стоит научится работать с bind_param. Ибо будет легче базе и будут исключены SQL-инъекции.

Comment: да мне знакомые говорили, что так проще. Но как-то мало информации, уроков по bind_param...
Количество s совпадает, i ставил. Да и не ставил тоже, просто в противном случаем должно записать "1", а должна быть "i", то-есть соответсвующий номер кнопки (поля ввода в форме).
Скорее всего мне нужно вникнуть в bind и разобраться конкретно с эти запросом. Спасибо!!

Comment: @VasilyUK Я пример поправил с учетом $i в запросе. На кошках потренируйтесь. тестовую табличку сделайте с несколькими колонками. и простенький скрипт, как в примерах к bind_param, (лучше из консоли запускать, что бы ошибки не пропустить). http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Я поправил сам и потом увидел изменения ;) Всё работает.
Спасибо еще раз! Буду читать.

Answer (score 1):

```
$keys = preg_grep("/BT[0-9]+_pair/",array_keys($_POST));
foreach($keys as $key){
    $value = $_POST[$key];
    .....
}
```